# Auth0 app_meta to store Confidential Information?

Tags: payment, auth0

I want to store Linux time stamp which determines the subscription done by user which changes when user pays for it. I'm using [Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/user-profile#structure-of-user-profile-data) , will app_meta be safe to store such data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps consider using the `user_profile` store. Auth0 intends this to be used as a supplement to each user, so storing something relevant to them (in this case, subscription information) is recommended.

And yes, your data is safe. Auth0 [recently completed our SOC2 audit](https://auth0.com/blog/2016/01/18/how-to-build-your-customer-trust-through-soc-2/) and you can read even more about how we protect customer data [on our website](https://auth0.com/security).